# Datatables not rendering ajax sourced json data

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, http-status-code-400

While trying to render a datatable with ajax sourced data, I get a

> 400 bad request

as ajax response.

The Json I get from the ajax call is as below which is happily validated by [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com)

```
{
    "data": {
        "title": "Seminar",
        "pdate": "2016-02-05",
        "duedate": "2016-03-04"
    }
}
```

I am using the following javascript suggested by datatables for rendering ajax sourced data ;

```
$('#table1').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '?r=site/test',
        type: 'POST',
        dataSrc: 'data'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'title' },
        { data: 'pdate' },
        { data: 'duedate' }
    ]
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vh55r2t/2/).

```
$b = [
'title'=>  "Seminar",
'pdate'=>  "2016-02-05",
'duedate' => "2016-03-04"

];

$a['data'][] = $b;
echo json_encode($a);
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`data` has to be an array of "rows"

From the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/data/):

> The **main data source** used for a DataTable **must always be an array** (it
>   is created automatically when using DOM sourced data). Each item in
>   that array will define a row to be displayed and DataTables can use
>   three basic Javascript data types as the data source for the rows
>
> - Arrays - `[]`
> - Objects - `{}`
> - Instances - `new MyClass()`

Hence the returned data from `?r=site/test` has to be

```
{
    "data": [{
        "title": "Seminar",
        "pdate": "2016-02-05",
        "duedate": "2016-03-04"
    }]
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtgs4cL3/1/)

Comment: can you kindly add a mock json response to the fiddle ?

Comment: just added to the question, the php code I'm using for the json request. Kindly check .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j6uozv9j/ works, but when I echo the same through JSON, it gives 400 bad request error.

Comment: The fiddle in my answer uses `/echo/json/` which returns whatever you're passing in as `data`.